# Convergence warnings missing from knit documents if fits wrapped in summary()

Tags: r, warnings, knitr, r-markdown

I use knitr/rmarkdown to document my analyses for others and myself.
The package I use, lme4, produces convergence warnings, which need to be documented.

If I run my model in the console, I get the warning right after, but the same warnings do not show inside the knit document, they end up in the Markdown console (i.e. after knitting is over).

It somehow depends on the [top-level function that is being executed](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/warning.html). To reproduce this, I tried creating a warning inside a function myself. This always showed in the Markdown.

While writing the question, it occured to me that I might play with `options(warn)`. Setting it to 1 makes the warnings occur immediately in the Markdown console, but not in the knit document itself.
This at least fixes this problem: if I get too many warnings, I'm asked to execute `warnings()` but can't do so in the knitting parent environment.

Here's a reproducible script:
http://rpubs.com/rubenarslan/missing_convergence_warnings

I've figured out that the convergence warnings are only hidden if I wrap the model fitting into `summary` like so `summary(m1 <- glmer(...))`, not if I do `m1 <- glmer(...); summary(m1)`. I borrowed [the example](http://rpubs.com/bbolker/lme4trouble1) and also found a way to get convergence warnings from the fit using this extractor `fit@optinfo$conv$lme4$messages`.

I can change my scripts now, but I don't really think it should be this way, I don't see a real difference between the two approaches, wrapping in summary is just more concise, the top-level function is knit in both cases.

Comment: Just the the completeness of the record: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/911

Comment: I think this actually occurs just the same with base-R constructs that throw warnings but are wrapped in `summary()`: see https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/263 for an example.  In particular, try an example with `summary(sqrt(-1))` ...

Comment: For completeness of the record, the bug was traced back further and resulted in an R level bug report: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16111 that has since been resolved